# ¿Cómo calcular el porcentaje de descuento del precio actual y el precio anterior?

Tags: php, mysqli

Cómo puedo mostrar el porcentaje en por cientos `%` de cuanto es el valor que se está aplicando el descuento del producto con el precio actual y el precio anterior.

**Ejemplo:**

Si en la base de datos tengo los siguientes registros en la tabla `products`

```
id_pro     price     price_old
  1        50.00      100.00
```

El siguiente mensaje a mostrar en la cartilla seria **$50.00 / 50% de descuento**

La consulta la realizo de la siguiente manera:

> **Nota:** El código `PHP` de la consulta se encuentra por encima del `HTML`

```
  if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE url='".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id_pro'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $price_old = $row['price_old'];
        }
    }
  }
```

Los resultados de la consulta lo muestro de la siguiente manera, dentro de cualquier contenido `HTML`.

```
<?php echo $price; ?>
```

Mi idea es poder tomar el valor de las dos variables `$price` y `$price_old` y por medio de ellas mostrar que porcentaje de descuento se está realizando.

> **Nota:** Siempre en cuando tomando en cuenta si existe o no un precio anterior registrado en la tabla, algunos productos no tendrán registro de un precio anterior en ese caso no existiría un porcentaje de descuento en la columna `price_old` de la tabla `products`

Mi idea seria algo así, pero tengo problemas en planteamiento del código `PHP` para mostrar los porcentajes tomando cuenta el **precio actual** y el **precio anterior.**

```
}else{
  echo "Aquí el porcentaje -> 50% de descuento";
}else {
  echo "No existe descuento -> En este caso no se mostrara un texto, quedara un echo vació";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar la regla de tres simple para calcular el porcentaje, en donde se multiplica los números cruzados y se divide por el que queda solo.

Suponiendo que tenemos un producto con un precio anterior de $120 y un precio actual de $60 el cálculo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$120 -> 100%
$60  -> x

x = (60 * 100) / 120
x = 50%
```

El valor de `x` es únicamente la diferencia porcentual que existe entre ambos precios. Para saber el descuento del producto solo queda calcular la diferencia entre `100%` y `x`.

En PHP quedaría así:

```
// Si existe el precio anterior
if ($price_old != null) {
    // Se calcula el porcentaje de descuento
    $descuento = 100 - ($price * 100 / $price_old);
    // Se asigna a mensaje el precio y el descuento
    $mensaje = "$" . price . "/" . $descuento . "% de descuento";
} else {
    // Se asigna solamente el precio a mensaje 
    $mensaje = "$" . price;
}
```

Comment: Existe este error **Notice: Undefined variable: descuento**  cuando no existe registro en la columna `price_old` recuerda amigo que no todos los productos contarán con registro de un precio anterior, cundo existe registro del precio actual y precio anterior funciona correctamente pero cuando no existe precio anterior muestra ese error.

Comment: amigo y como soluciono el error cuando no existe registro de un precio anterior?

Comment: Edite la respuesta

Comment: Perfecto funciona pero ahora existe un problema en un producto con un precio actual de **10.00** y un precio anterior de **100.00** me muestra que existe un porcentaje de descuento del **10% de descuento** pero debería ser el 90% de descuento amigo, mi tabla columna de `price` y `price_old` esta de tipo `double(9,2)` sera ese el problema o sera otro?

Comment: Volví a actualizar la respuesta